# Is extra time on the GRE looked down upon?

Tags: gre, disability

I have a friend who generally gets extra time on tests within my University, but is worried that if she requests it on the Math GRE it'll be denoted on her scores somehow, and places she's applying to may count it against her.  So, I have the following questions:

1. Does the Math GRE subject test currently indicate whether a student used extra time on the exam (as a disability accomodation)?
2. If so, how do grad schools in Math/CS take this information into consideration?

Comment: I've never seen extra time reported next to GRE scores.  But then again, I don't care about GRE scores.

Comment: Not a lawyer but, I'm pretty certain any such reporting would be against the ADA Act. So no it shouldn't be reported in any way.

Comment: @scrappedcola I agree I personally would find it very odd if it was reported, but I'm mostly hoping for someone with firsthand experience to confirm/deny it (which JeffE's comment does to a certain extent).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ETS *used to* "flag" the scores of anyone who took the GRE under what they referred to as "non-standard test conditions". After an Americans With Disabilities Act lawsuit they settled and agreed to no longer flag scores, and [according to their website](https://www.ets.org/disabilities/test_takers/faq/):

> **I heard that ETS is no longer flagging test scores that are reported to score recipients. Is this true?**
>
> ETS has discontinued flagging almost all scores for tests that are
>   taken with accommodations. For example, if a test taker receives
>   additional time or extra breaks, the score will no longer be flagged
>   in the report. In rare instances, ETS will flag the score report as a
>   "nonstandard administration" only if the test is significantly
>   altered.

This is true for other related tests, such as the GMAT. Note that this last line about "significantly altered" means some accommodation that requires a whole section to be removed, or the test to be heavily altered in some other way, and does not apply to just extra time or similarly regular adjustments.

A person seeking accommodations will still need to request them well in advance of the test from ETS, and will need to provide appropriate medical information in order for them to approve the request.